# Missing characters from Hebrew font in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Using Google Chrome on Ubuntu 18.04, I sometimes see pages that appear like this:
[image]

Downloading the [source](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24375/does-the-bible-ever-say-that-the-ark-of-the-covenant-flew-or-levitated#answer-55064) and viewing it in "vim" shows:
[image]

(The characters in the source need to be read right-to-left.)

The `hexdump` command shows:

```
0000000   <   s   t   r   o   n   g   >   �   �   �   �   �   �   �   �
0000000    733c    7274    6e6f    3e67    a0d7    b4d6    aad7    bcd6
0000010   �   �   �   �   � 227   � 225   �   �   <   /   s   t   r   o  
0000010    b0d6    a7d7    97d6    95d7    bcd6    2f3c    7473    6f72  
0000020   n   g   >       � 233   �   �   �   �   �   �   �   �   � 225  
0000020    676e    203e    9bd7    bcd6    b7d6    a4d7    bcd6    95d7  
0000030   �   �   �   �   � 231       �   �   �   �   � 222   �   �   �  
0000030    b9d6    aad7    99d6    d720    d6a8    d7b7    d692    d7b0  
0000040 234   �   �   �   �   � 231       � 224   �   �   � 233   �   �  
0000040    d69c    d6b5    d7a3    2099    94d7    b7d6    9bd7    bcd6  
0000050   �   �   � 224   �   �   �   �   �   �   � 224   � 231   � 235  
0000050    b9d6    94d7    b2d6    a0d7    b4d6    94d6    99d7    9dd7  
0000060       � 220   �   �   � 226   � 234       � 224   �   �   � 227  
0000060    d720    d690    d6b6    d796    209c    94d7    b6d6    97d7  
0000070   �   �   �   �   �   �   � 221   �   �   � 221   � 224       <  
0000070    b8d6    a8d7    b8d6    91d7    b8d6    91d6    94d7    3c20  
0000080   /   p   >  \n                                            
0000080    702f    0a3e
```

Six of the characters each appear as multiple unknown characters on the web page.
Am I missing some font, or is this a bug in Google Chrome, or in Ubuntu, or what?

Comment: Please share a link that illustrates your problem so that people with other browsers can take a look.

Comment: In Firefox 66.0.3 on Ubuntu 19.04 it is displayed as a string of hebrew characters (which I can't read and which I never installed). So I suspect the bug woulg be in Chrome.

Comment: @DKBose, the "Downloading the source" phrase contained a link to the Christianity.SE question.  (I've just updated it to point to the specific answer.)

Comment: @muclux, I've now submitted a bug report to Google.